# Extract wrong Month from Date

Tags: javascript

I used following code:

```
var date = $('#datefromcal').val();
            var dt = new Date(date);
            alert(dt); // RESULT=  Wed May 21 12:00:00 UTC+0200 2014
            alert("Date : " + dt.getDate());//RESULT= Date : 21
            alert("Month : " + dt.getMonth());//RESULT= Month : 4 
            alert("Year : " + dt.getFullYear()); //RESULT= Year : 2014
```

I try to extract Day, Month and Year. I allways received Month: 4, but now is May. My results are shown in comments.

Can somebody explain me why it happens? Or how to extract month.

Thanks

Comment: Month is `0` based (0 for January). 4 is correct for May

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) method returns the month in the specified date
>   according to local time, as a **zero-based** value (where zero indicates
>   the first month of the year).
>
> The value returned by getMonth is an integer between 0 and 11. 0
>   corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

Comment: But I tried to extract from following time: Wed May 21 12:00:00 UTC+0200 2014. Why getMonth() return "4"?

Comment: Because May is 4th month (January being the 0th).

Answer (score 0):

`Date.getMonth()` is 0 based.

January=0, February=1, March=2, April=3, May=4 ...